# When configuring the innodb_buffer_pool_size should the value be different if you have a lot of small websites vs. a single one?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

The general rule of thumb I've observed is configuring this property to use 70% of available RAM for dedicated SQL servers with over 4GB RAM.  However I'm working on what basically amounts to a shared hosting environment experiencing a ton of traffic lately and I want to optimize this - these are dedicated mySQL servers, but have databases for 200-1000 different sites.  Should I still configure using this rule?

Comment: "a ton of traffic" -- a ton of connections?  of selects?  of updates?  of tables?  ...  See this for getting more detailed analysis:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis  (It probably won't suggest changing the 70%.  If you are swapping, it is too big.)

Answer (score 0):

You may have many tables and schemas in your MySQL instance, but a single buffer pool is used for all of them. It makes no difference what they're used for — one website or many websites or some database that is not for a website at all. Basically everything that is stored in a page of an InnoDB tablespace on that MySQL instance must be loaded into the buffer pool before it can be read or updated.

The recommendation of 70% of available RAM is not a magic number.

For example, it assumes you have a lot more data on storage than can fit in RAM. If you had 100GB of RAM and 2GB of data on storage, it would be unnecessary overkill to make a 70GB buffer pool. The pages from storage will only be copied into the buffer pool once, therefore for 2GB of data, your 70GB buffer pool would be mostly empty.

It also assumes that the remaining 30% of RAM is enough to support your operating system and other processes besides MySQL.

70% is just a starting suggestion. You need to understand your memory needs to size it properly.